# Delete link instead of button laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a delete link that links to destroy button

```html
<i class="icon-trash"></i>
<a style="color:black" href="route{{ action('TasksController@destroy', ['id' => $task->id ,'method'=>'DELETE'] ) }}">
  delete
</a>
```

This is the destroy function

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    //delete task
    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->delete();

    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Task deleted successfully');
}
```

but the link is not working when clicked

Comment: what's your route in `web.php` file?? are you trying to use delete in an anchor tag??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Blade` syntax is incorrect, change it to

```html
<i class="icon-trash"></i>
<a style="color:black" href="{{ route('tasks.destroy', ['id' => $task->id]) }}">
    delete
</a>
```

Which requires a route like this

```php
Route::get('/tasks/delete/{id}', 'TasksController@destroy')
     ->name('tasks.destroy');
```

And a controller method like this

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
  // delete task
  $task=Task::find($id);
  $task->delete();
  return redirect('/home')->with('success','Task deleted successfully');
}
```

## NOTE:

Having a get method to delete is a security vulnerability as anyone can trick other users into deleting tasks just by providing a link

### Change it to a post method

### EDIT:

Here are some suggestions to improve your code

Change your HTML to perform a post request

```html
<i class="icon-trash"></i>
<a style="color:black" 
    href="{{ route('tasks.destroy', ['task' => $task]) }}"
    onclick="event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('delete-form-{{ $task->id }}').submit();">
    delete
</a>

<form id="delete-form-{{ $task->id }}" action="{{ route('tasks.destroy', ['task' => $task]) }}"
     method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
</form>
```

Route with route model binding

```php
Route::get('/tasks/delete/{task}', 'TasksController@destroy')
     ->name('tasks.destroy');
```

Controller method with dependency injection

```php
public function destroy(Task $task)
{
  // delete task
  $task->delete();
  return redirect('/home')->with('success','Task deleted successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anchor tags are for `GET` requests. You can't use this for `POST` or `DELETE`. If you want to delete using an anchor tag you have to use a `GET` request which is not recommended for deleting an entry. Though it will be something like below

```
<a href="{{ route('task.destroy',$task->id) }}">
    Delete
</a>
```

Set your route like

```
Route::get('task/delete/{id}', 'TasksController@destroy')
     ->name('task.destroy');
```

And your current controller code will do just fine.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->delete();
    return redirect('/home')->with('success','Task Deleted Successfully');
}
```

Well now lets do it with `DELETE` method.

Route

```
Route::delete('task/delete/{id}', 'TasksController@destroy')
         ->name('task.destroy');
```

Send the delete request using a form

```
<form action="{{ route('task.destroy', $task->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

You can do it using a `POST` method too.

```
Route::post('task/delete/{id}', 'TasksController@destroy')
         ->name('task.destroy');

<form action="{{ route('task.destroy', $task->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Your controller code will remain same. My recommendation is either use `POST` or `DELETE` method to destroy an item from database.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this: (you can pass your id)

```
<form action="{{ route('tasks.destroy', $dummy->id) }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="this.closest('form').submit();return false;">
              <i class="bi bi-trash-fill" style="color:white"></i>
           </a>
 </form>
```

requires route like:

```
Route::get('/tasks/delete/{id}', 'TasksController@destroy')
     ->name('tasks.destroy');
```

your controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->delete();
    return redirect('/home')->with('success','Task Deleted Successfully');
}
```

or you can try this

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['reports.destroy', $dummy->id],'class'=>'']) !!}
      {{ Form::button('<i class="bi bi-trash-fill" style="color:white"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'delete get-started-btn-two'] )  }}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```